# ¿tecla enter no me envia correctamente los formularios?

Tags: php, html, jquery

estoy usando `bootstrapValidator` para validar mis form.

pero tengo un problema al querer enviar el formulario, con la **tecla enter**,
es decir si faltan campos por llenar o algunos campos son incorrectos al presionar tecla enter se validan y muestra si los campos estan bien diligenciados o no, pero cuando los campos estan bien diligenciados al presionar la tecla enter es como si se estuviera enviado el form, se cierra el form, pero el form sigue ahi en el metodo `POST`, no se envian.

En cambio cuando los forms los envio atravez de las tecla de submit, se envian sin nigun problema.
no se como puedo hacer para que se envien tambien con la tecla enter.

estoy enviando el form atravez del metodo POST, y asi se recibe en el servidor.

NOTA:

> segun las pruebas que he hecho, el problema esta cuando le agrego un
> name al boton submit, como hago que al presionar la tecla enter se
> envie el name del buttom submit? se envie su atributo, ya que en php
> estoy preguntando si existe el nombre de ese atributo, si existe deja
> continuar con el registro.

```
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--****************************************************
                MODAL REGISTRAR DATOS
********************************************************-->
<div id="modalRegistrar" class="modal " data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <form class="form registerForm" role="form" method="post" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <!--****************************************************
                CABEZA MODAL
                ********************************************************-->

                <div class="modal-header" style="background: #444444b4; color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">

                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i> REGISTRAR</h4>

                </div>

                <!--****************************************************
                CUERPO DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="box-body">

                        <!-------------------------------------------->
                        <!--PERSONA-RESPONSABLE-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
                            <label class="control-label">OPERARIO:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <input  class="form-control large-input prohibido-no" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["nombre"]; ?>" readonly>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--CÓDIGO-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
                            <label class="control-label" for="text">CÓDIGO:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control puntero-i codigoP" name="newinputCodigo" id="newCodigo" placeholder="INGRESE CÓDIGO" required>
                                <input type="hidden" name="classprod" id="classProd" value="1">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--NOMBRE PRODUCTO-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
                            <label class="control-label" for="text">NOMBRE PRODUCTO:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control puntero-i" name="newinputNameProd" id="newNameProd" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['newinputCodigo'])) {echo $_POST['newinputCodigo'];}else{ echo(' no existe');}  ?>" placeholder="NOMBRE PRODUCTO" readonly>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--UNIDADES-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
                            <label class="control-label" for="text">UNIDADES:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control puntero-i" name="newinputUnidad" id="newUnidad" placeholder="INGRESE UNIDADES" required>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!--KILOS-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
                            <label class="control-label" for="text">KILOS:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control puntero-i" name="newinputKilos" id="newKilos" placeholder="INGRESE KILOS" required>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!--DETALLE-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
                            <label for="control-label">DETALLE:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" name="newinputDetalle" id="newDetalle" rows="3" placeholder="INGRESE DETALLE" required>N/A</textarea>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--****************************************************
                PIE DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left manito-clic" id="salir-pk" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manito-clic submit1" name="registrar1" disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
                </div>

                <!--CREAMOS OBJETO PHP PARA EJECUTAR EL MÉTODO CREAR-->

                <?php

                    $crear1 = new Controlador1();
                    $crear1 -> ctrCrear1();
                ?>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

este es mi archio php donde pregunto si existe la tecla submit.

```
<?php

static public function ctrCrear1(){

    if(isset($_POST["registrar1"])){

        /*******promedio ************/
        $tlpro=$_POST["newinputKilos"]/$_POST["newinputUnidad"];

        $tab = "tb1";
        $dat = array("pers_resp" => $_SESSION["name_user"],
                    "modulo_user" => 1,
                    "clas_producc" => $_POST["classprod"],
                    "codi_product" => $_POST["newinputCodigo"],
                    "unidad_product" => $_POST["newinputUnidad"],
                    "kils_produc" => $_POST["newinputKilos"],
                    "promedio_ku_producc" => $tlpro,
                    "detalle_product" => $_POST["newinputDetalle"]
        );

        $rep = Modelo1::MdlCrear1($tab $dat);

        if ($rep == "ok") {

            echo '<script>

                swal.fire({

                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    backdrop: `rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.4)`,
                    allowEscapeKey: false,
                    icon: "success",
                    title: "¡Los Datos Fueron Registrados Correctamente!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"

                    }).then(function(result){

                    if(result.value){
                        window.location = "piku";
                    }

                });

            </script>';

        }else{

            echo '<script>

                swal.fire({

                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    backdrop: `rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.4)`,
                    allowEscapeKey: false,
                    icon: "error",
                    title: "¡ESTA HABIENDO PROBLEMAS AL REGISTRAR LOS DATOS COMPRUEBE QUE ESTÉN BIEN DILIGENCIADOS Ó CONTACTE AL ADMINISTRADOR SÍ PERSISTE ESTE PROBLEMA!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"

                    }).then(function(result){

                    if(result.value){
                        window.location = "piku";
                    }

                });

            </script>';

        }//fin else

    }//fin isset principal

}
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar tu código HTML y Javascript, de otra forma no podemos saber porqué no funciona como esperas.

Comment: segun las pruebas que he hecho, el problema esta cuando le agrego un name a el boton submit, entonces como hago que al presionar la tecla enter se envie el name del buttom name?

Comment: Los elementos _button_ no son enviados por formulario, si lo necesitas, cámbialo por _input_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

analizando mi codigo,
encontre dos cosas,

**1.** desde el servidor como primer parametro estaba evaluando si venia el atributo name con algun valor del boton submit.

**2.** cuando pulsaba el boton submit desde cualquier form, llegaba corretamente ese valor al servidor, pero cuando pulsaba enter el form se enviaba, pero en nigun lugar del servidor recibia ese valor, y en realidad no se enviaba ese valor.

esto ocurre porque cuando pulsamo el boton registrar se esta enviando aparte del form los atributos que tenga en ese boton, pero cuando pulsamo enter se envia el form es decir todos los inputs ya sea que esten ocultos o no.

mi solucion fue crear un input de tipo hidden con el name que tenia el boton,
con esto tanto si pulsamos enter o el boton registrar(submit) se estaria enviando el valor que estoy evaluado como primer paramatro, es como un tipo de indentificador unico, ya que a todos los form su atributo name que evalua el servidor es diferente, no repetitibo para asegurarme que el form llegue a lugar correcto.

ejemplo:

**como lo tenia:**

***haciendo click en boton submit****

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left manito-clic" id="salir-pk" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manito-clic submit1" name="registrar1" disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
                </div>
```

**mi solucion**

agrego campo input y añado el atributo que estaba en el boton de enviar.

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="registrar1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left manito-clic" id="salir-pk" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manito-clic submit1"  disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

veo que en tu código tienes inhabilitado el botón registrar

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left manito-clic" id="salir-pk"
                data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manito-clic submit1" name="registrar1"
                disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
        </div>
```

Solo quita el valor **disabled** al boton registrar y este tomara efecto a la hora que presiones enter, siempre y cuando estés dentro del formulario.

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left manito-clic" id="salir-pk"
                data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manito-clic submit1" name="registrar1"
                >REGISTRAR</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: bueno bro ese no es el problema, como dije estoy usando bootstrapValidator , que es el que habilita el botom si los datos estan bien dilegenciados, pero ya vi cual es el poblema, resulta que se presiona la tecla de registrar la cual contiene el atributo name, que es el que estoy recibiendo como primer valor en php (se envie correctamente), a diferencia de que cuando presiono enter, solo se envia los inputs, es como si el boton no existiera, lo que quiero saber es que cuando presione enter me envie el name del botom registrar.

Comment: mi solucion fue crear otro campo input de tipo hidden y alli pegar el name del butom y asi funciona tanto si presiono enter como si presiono el botom registrar, pero como tegon muchos form con el mismo problema, quiero saber como se puede hacer que al presionar enter me envie el name del buttom submit.

Comment: Comprendo, puedes agregar al boton submit el atributo value="valorDeseado" de esta manera cuando recuperes mediante post o get recibirás ese valor